# Button state change when opening option menu

Tags: button, android-activity, android

Why does a button that is pressed, lose it's state when opening the options menu?

I made a sample activity to make it clear:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);             
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setPressed(true); // set the state
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
            return true;
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

We set the button in our view to the pressed state.
When you run the project and then open the options menu, the pressed state is gone. It looks like the button has removed it's state.

What is the solution/workaround to keep the button state without redrawing the whole activity? Perhaps the implementation of a Button is not ment to have this behaviour and a toggle button needs to be used?

Comment: Menu button can only be focused only when you have clicked it. It looses it's focus as the click is released.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);             
    btn; = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setPressed(true); // set the state
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    //here you can set your state....
    btn. //set the state...
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
            return true;
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```